# How to update tile created by other app?

Tags: windows-phone

I have two app: one UI to create a tile with Create(), the other agent to update the tile with Update(). The 2 functions worked well in one app, ie. both in UI or both in agent. But if I put Create in UI and Update() in agent, Update() can not find the tile created by Create(). What's wrong? Thanks.

```
    private void Create()
    {
        ShellTile find = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("ID=shelltile"));
        StandardTileData date = new StandardTileData();
        date.Count = 10;
        if (find == null)
        {
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?ID=shelltile", UriKind.Relative), date);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        ShellTile find = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("ID=shelltile"));
        if (find != null)
        {
            StandardTileData date = new StandardTileData();
            date.Title = "aaaaaaaaa";
            find.Update(date);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each app can only access its own tiles.  If you want to update the tiles, you'll need to make a [background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in the same app.  (note that a [background agent can't create tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which leads me to believe this isn't what you're doing now)

Comment: So I have to Create() and Update() in my agent (assume I can), then is there any way to launch the UI when user click the tile? I search through internet but didn't find how to write the URI launching another app.

Comment: @wizardlee No, you cannot launch App1 by clicking the tile of App2. A tile can launch it's own app (the app that created it). Why do you want 2 different apps anyways. Why not have the same app have a UI and a background agent?

Comment: You can't Create() in your agent - it's one of the APIs that doesn't work in a background agent.